# pgpool, pcp_recovery_node command failed

Tags: database, postgresql, recovery, pgpool

I made HA PostgreSQL, so I use `pgpool` service.

I need to use `pcp_recovery_node` command. When I run the command :

```
psql -h 192.168.31.xxx (my-VIP address) -p 9898 -U pgpool -n 0 (pgpool_node_id)
```

I encountered this error:

```
ERROR:  executing recovery, execution of command failed at "1st stage"
2024-03-04 16:01:09: pid 46889: DETAIL:  command:"/data/pgsql/13/data/recovery_1st_stage"
```

I changed just one script:

```
# vi /data/pgsql/13/data/recovery_1st_stage (/data/pgsql/13/data/ <- my PGDATA path)
ARCHIVEDIR=/data/pgsql/13/archive
```

I follow this reference: https://concave.tistory.com/22#Reference